# Public Test Swarm for JSUnit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, jsunit, testswarm

I came across Test Swarm which jQuery uses for running JSUnit (Qunit) tests across all browsers (real ones). I can download and install test swarm on my machine and get loads of VMs fired up to load and connect all browsers, but I was wondering if there is a service around it already?

Configuring all browsers (including mobile ones) and getting them connected to testSwamp to run my tests is a big pain. Is there a public community / swamp where I can get an access so that I can submit my jobs and get the results back by some callback something?

Any other alternative to this?

Thanks

Sparsh Gupta

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate TestSwarm with a browser virtualization service as an alternative. Here are a few:

- [MogoTest](https://bitbucket.org/mogotest/)
- [CrossBrowserTesting](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/)
- [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/)
- [Browserling](https://browserling.com/)